Azure Powershell to set failover Group secondary to standby mode
I have an Azure SQL Failover Group. I need to set the replica type to standby, using the Powershell module.
I don't see a commandlet that lets me set the replica type (also called secondary type).
I see the Set-AzSqlDatabaseInstanceFailoverGroup commandlet, but that only works for a managed instance. I need it for Azure SQL.
Which commandlet should I use?


Azure Powershell to set failover Group secondary to standby mode in azure SQL

In Azure SQL there is no Option to Update the Secondary type value to Standby While creation only you need to select it when you configure a new active geo-replication relationship or creating replica database using PowerShell command:

New-AzSqlDatabaseSecondary

New-AzSqlDatabaseSecondary [-DatabaseName] <String> [-SecondaryServiceObjectiveName <String>] [-SecondaryElasticPoolName <String>] [-Tags <Hashtable>] [-SecondaryType <String>]

